# Unable to set some colorschemes in NeoVim

Tags: neovim, colorscheme

I have added few colorschemes to my `colors` folder for NeoVim and they also show up when I press **Tab**. I can see all the exact themes that are in the `colors` folder.
[image: all colorschemes]

But, I am only able to use a few themes out of those.
When I select any of those (themes in the colors folder) themes, it doesn't change the colorscheme, and when I type `:colorscheme` to view the current colorscheme it shows **onedark** (one of the few themes that are working).

Comment: Perhaps they are not installed correctly?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I don't think they are.